# SwiftUI image asset scaling always shows the smallest image

Tags: swift

I have an image of size 300x100. I want the image size to stay the same in IPhone 11 and other big screens, while I want an image with sizes of 100x33 and 200x66 to be used for smaller screens. I have resized the images and put them in 1x,2x and 3x boxes, but the smallest image is being shown on all devices.

Comment: what is the original size of your image?
If it's 100x3 and you have changed that image in rest of them, it'll not work.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper the original is 300x100, i scaled the others down

Comment: Make sure:
1. You are not adding 1x image in your bundle with same name. It should be only in assets.
2. You are not adding 1z image at 2x and 3x boxes in assets.

Comment: @bestiosdeveloper checked them all. It's the same